# Pass two values to a parameter

Tags: powerquery

I have the custom function code below to lookup information by an API and an NPI number. The API is based on several values in a selected column. The NPI is harcoded (e.g. 1111111111 in example below), but looking to use several NPIs listed in a separate table (e.g. table "Providers" and column NPI).  Any ideas to modify code to accomplish this? Thanks

```
(eAPI) =>

let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://data.cms.gov/data-api/v1/dataset/" & Text.From(eAPI) & "/data?filter[Rndrng_NPI]=1111111111")),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"Rndrng_NPI", "Rndrng_Prvdr_Last_Org_Name", "Rndrng_Prvdr_First_Name", "Rndrng_Prvdr_MI", "Rndrng_Prvdr_Crdntls", "Rndrng_Prvdr_Gndr", "Rndrng_Prvdr_Ent_Cd", "Rndrng_Prvdr_St1", "Rndrng_Prvdr_St2", "Rndrng_Prvdr_City", "Rndrng_Prvdr_State_Abrvtn", "Rndrng_Prvdr_State_FIPS", "Rndrng_Prvdr_Zip5", "Rndrng_Prvdr_RUCA", "Rndrng_Prvdr_RUCA_Desc", "Rndrng_Prvdr_Cntry", "Rndrng_Prvdr_Type", "Rndrng_Prvdr_Mdcr_Prtcptg_Ind", "HCPCS_Cd", "HCPCS_Desc", "HCPCS_Drug_Ind", "Place_Of_Srvc", "Tot_Benes", "Tot_Srvcs", "Tot_Bene_Day_Srvcs", "Avg_Sbmtd_Chrg", "Avg_Mdcr_Alowd_Amt", "Avg_Mdcr_Pymt_Amt", "Avg_Mdcr_Stdzd_Amt"}, {"Rndrng_NPI", "Rndrng_Prvdr_Last_Org_Name", "Rndrng_Prvdr_First_Name", "Rndrng_Prvdr_MI", "Rndrng_Prvdr_Crdntls", "Rndrng_Prvdr_Gndr", "Rndrng_Prvdr_Ent_Cd", "Rndrng_Prvdr_St1", "Rndrng_Prvdr_St2", "Rndrng_Prvdr_City", "Rndrng_Prvdr_State_Abrvtn", "Rndrng_Prvdr_State_FIPS", "Rndrng_Prvdr_Zip5", "Rndrng_Prvdr_RUCA", "Rndrng_Prvdr_RUCA_Desc", "Rndrng_Prvdr_Cntry", "Rndrng_Prvdr_Type", "Rndrng_Prvdr_Mdcr_Prtcptg_Ind", "HCPCS_Cd", "HCPCS_Desc", "HCPCS_Drug_Ind", "Place_Of_Srvc", "Tot_Benes", "Tot_Srvcs", "Tot_Bene_Day_Srvcs", "Avg_Sbmtd_Chrg", "Avg_Mdcr_Alowd_Amt", "Avg_Mdcr_Pymt_Amt", "Avg_Mdcr_Stdzd_Amt"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Column1",{"Rndrng_Prvdr_Gndr", "Rndrng_Prvdr_Ent_Cd", "Rndrng_Prvdr_St1", "Rndrng_Prvdr_St2", "Rndrng_Prvdr_City", "Rndrng_Prvdr_State_Abrvtn", "Rndrng_Prvdr_State_FIPS", "Rndrng_Prvdr_Zip5", "Rndrng_Prvdr_RUCA", "Rndrng_Prvdr_RUCA_Desc", "Rndrng_Prvdr_Cntry", "Rndrng_Prvdr_Type", "Rndrng_Prvdr_Mdcr_Prtcptg_Ind"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",{{"Avg_Mdcr_Alowd_Amt", Currency.Type}, {"Avg_Mdcr_Pymt_Amt", Currency.Type}, {"Avg_Mdcr_Stdzd_Amt", Currency.Type}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type",{{"Avg_Mdcr_Stdzd_Amt", Order.Descending}})

in

    #"Sorted Rows"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add it to the parameter list, e.g.

```
(eAPI, NPI) =>
```

Comment: Tried this and got an Error message.  How do I reference the NPI in a different table?

Comment: They have to be in the same table, so you'll have to merge the data prior to calling the custom function.

Comment: Ahh. Your right. Was trying a different approach. Thanks.